# Calculating a norm of a sum of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a book and there is this stated there

$$||\sum _i ^n (v_i^T \eta)v_i|| = \gamma$$

Where in the problem we are using the normal Euclidean norm and $v_i\in \mathbb{R} ^n$, and orthonormal and $||\eta||=\gamma$. I just want to go over the computation and make sure I understand how we derive it

$$||\sum _i ^n (v_i^T \eta)v_i|| = \sum_i ^N ||(v_i^T \eta)v_i||= \sum |(v_i^T \eta)|||v_i||$$

From here how I understand is that $||v_i||$ vanishes and we compute only the coefficients but how I understand it it should be $N\gamma$ because we are adding the norm of $\eta$ N times assuming $v_i$ and $\eta$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: Let $V$ be the matrix with columns $v_{1},\ldots,v_{n}.$ Since $V^{T}V=I,$ also $VV^{T}=I,$ and thus $\eta=VV^{T}\eta=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(v_{i}^{T}\eta)v_{i}.$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\left\Vert\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (v_{i}^{T}\eta) v_{1} \right\Vert = \gamma \\
\implies & \left\Vert\eta\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{i}^{T}v_{i} \right\Vert = \gamma \tag{since $\eta$ is a constant} 
\end{align}

Now it seems that due to some properties $\sum_{i = 1}^{n}v_{i}^{T}v_{i} = 1$. Hence you can conclude that $\Vert \eta \Vert = \gamma$.